# React-Native Image is not displaying after XCode 11.5 Upgrade

Tags: ios, xcode, image, react-native, build

I usually display images like this:

```
<Image source={require('../../assets/images/color/stuff.png')} />
<Image source={require('../some-other-path/picture.png')} />
```

In the past, I could have any arbitrary path I want, in any folder.

Then, when I build for release, I do this before I Build > Run:

```
react-native bundle --platform ios --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output ./ios/main.jsbundle
```

Since upgrading to XCode, whenever I do a *release* build, my images no longer appear. In dev build, the images are visible.

I have tried `--assets-dest ./some-folder`, but the results are same.

What could cause this change?

Comment: please add react-native info in question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solution 1:

In my case I was using resizeMode='center' and when I changed from 'center' to 'contain' it solved my problem.

## Solution 2:

1. Navigate to project directory => `ios` => Create folder `assets`

[image]

2. Inside folder `assets` => create folder structure same as folder where
   you keep image in the project (In my case I kept all the images in
   `app > src > assets > image`) and copy all images to this folder
3. Open Xcode => Select project target => `Build Phases`
4. Drag folder `assets` which we have created into `Copy Bundle Resources`

[image]

5. Select `Copy items if needed and press Finish`

[image]

6. Clean project and Build release again

**Done!**

PS: If your images name like this `my_image.ios.jpg` you need to rename them to `my_image.jpg`.

## Solution 3:

In **Build Phases > Bundle React Native code and images** replace any lines you have for this:

```
export NODE_BINARY=node ../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react-native-xcode.sh
```

After, delete main.jsbundle file from xcode and from the folder and remake it again:

```
react-native bundle --entry-file='index.js' --bundle-output='./ios/main.jsbundle' --dev=false --platform='ios' --assets-dest='./ios'
```

After, add the generated main.jsbundle again. Clean, build and run the project again.

Answer (score 0):

The way I handled in my code is to create a separate module for different formats under the `src` directory as `@types`

so these two files below will be under `src/types`

`png.d.ts`

```
declare module '*.png' {
  const __pngImage__: unique symbol;
  const image: number & { __ext__: typeof __pngImage__ };
  export default image;
}
```

similarly for jpg

`jpg.d.ts`

```
declare module '*.jpg' {
  const __jpgImage__: unique symbol;
  const image: number & { __ext__: typeof __jpgImage__ };
  export default image;
}
```

And then import normally in the component

```
import my_image from 'assets/images/my_image.png';
```

and use it like below

```
<View>
    <Image src = {my_image} />
</View>
```